# Use of Cast Projection inside a Concat Projection

Tags: nhibernate, projection, queryover

I have the following query:

```
var result = _session.QueryOver<Entity>()
    .Where(e => e.Property == value)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(f => Projections.Concat("prefix-", e.BigIntProperty)).WithAlias(() => alias.Whatever)
        ...
    )
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<Model>())
    .Future<Model>();
```

The problem is that `Projections.Concat()` accepts only strings and since `e.BigIntProperty` is not, the above doesn't compile. Is there a way to cast `e.BigIntProperty` to string?

I tried something like the following, which doesn't work either:

```
.Select(f => Projections.Concat("prefix-", Projection.Cast(NHibernateUtil.String, e.BigIntProperty))).WithAlias(() => alias.Whatever)
```

, since `Projections.Cast` returns an `IProjection` and not a string.

Comment: In this case, much more easier would be to return just BigIntProperty as some int/long property, and create the other property converting that value **anyhow** in C#...

Comment: Yes, this is the way I currently overcome this (using Linq on the List that is returned), but I'd like to know if there is a 'proper' way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Projections.Cast` seems terribly limited in that it can't take arbitrary `Projection`s. Luckily you can easily create your own custom projection that enables you to do that:

```
public static class CustomProjections
{
    public static IProjection Concat(params IProjection[] projections)
    {
        return Projections.SqlFunction(
            "concat",
            NHibernateUtil.String,
            projections);
    }
}
```

Then, you'll be able to use your `CustomProjections` class like this:

```
var result = _session.QueryOver<Entity>()
    .Where(e => e.Property == value)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(CustomProjections.Concat(
            Projections.Constant("prefix-"),
            Projections.Cast(
                NHibernateUtil.String,
                Projections.Property<Entity>(e => e.BigIntProperty))))
            .WithAlias(() => alias.Whatever)
        ...
    )
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<Model>())
    .Future<Model>();
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to build myself, but I couldn't get it right. I'll include another solution I came up with just for reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've already accepted Andrew's answer, but just for reference, you could use `Projections.SqlFunction("concat", ...)` directly which solves the whole issue since it can take `IProjection`'s as arguments and not only string.

```
var result = _session.QueryOver<Entity>()
    .Where(e => e.Property == value)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(Projections.SqlFunction("concat",
            NHibernateUtil.String,
            Projections.Constant("prefix-"),
            Projections.Cast(NHibernateUtil.String, Projections.Property<Entity>(e => e.BigIntProperty))))               
        .WithAlias(() => alias.Whatever)
        ...
     )
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<Model>())
    .Future<Model>();
```

**NOTE**: It seems that when calling either `Projections.Concat(...)` or `Projections.SqlFunction("concat", ...)`, the query that is produced actually uses the `+` operator, e.g.:

```
SELECT (a + b) as foo FROM table
```

instead of:

```
SELECT concat(a, b) as foo FROM table
```

Of course, `CONCAT` is only available from MS SQL Server versions 2012 and above, so this is correct. Possibly the `MsSQl2012Dialect` could make use of the `CONCAT`, since **`CONCAT` doesn't require that the arguments are varchar, they might as well be integers**.

Unfortunately `MsSQl2012Dialect` doesn't do that, but it is very easy to build a custom Dialect:

```
public class CustomMsSql2012Dialect : MsSql2012Dialect
{
    protected override void RegisterFunctions()
    {
        base.RegisterFunctions();
        base.RegisterFunction("concat", new VarArgsSQLFunction(NHibernateUtil.String, "concat(", ",", ")"));
    }
}
```

So, if you use version 2012 or above and you declare the above as your `Dialect`, you can ditch the `Projections.Cast(...)` part